# Infusionsoft XML RPC API

Tags: xml-rpc, infusionsoft

I am trying to find if a particular tag is applied on a contact. But I am not sure which method to use. I am using infuionsoft XML rpc API https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/ and using PHP. I can add or remove tags from a contact. Here is how I have started

```
###Set up the call to add to the group###
$call = new xmlrpcmsg("DataService.query", array(
    php_xmlrpc_encode('ourapikey'), #The encrypted API key
    php_xmlrpc_encode('ContactGroupAssign'), //Table to search for tag
    php_xmlrpc_encode(1), //limit
    php_xmlrpc_encode(0), //number of pages 
    php_xmlrpc_encode('Contact.Id => ~=~ 12566'), //i am searching for this contact id

));

###Send the call###
$result = $client->send($call);
 if ($result->faultCode()) {
    echo $result->faultCode() . "<BR>";
    echo $result->faultString() . "<BR>";
}else{
    print_r($result);
}
```

But I am getting **No method matching arguments** error. Any help would be highly appricated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means the method you're trying to communicate with expects to get another parameters.

For a start, taking a closer look at the [documentation](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#data-query-a-data-table), you may see **selectedFields** is required and **queryData** must be a struct, with PHP you can use an array.

In your case, these parameters may look this way
**queryData** `['ContactId' => 12566]`
**selectedFields** `['ContactId', 'GroupId']`